# /usr/bin/ssh and /usr/sbin/sshd can't be moved to update openssh-server and openssh-client because of immutable attribute

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, software-updates, xattr

Ubuntu Server can't be upgraded because it says that `openssh-sftp-server` package have unmet dependencies

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-sftp-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2) but 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.1 is installed
```

When I try to use `apt --fix-broken install` to install what is missing I receive the following output:

```
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-server_1%3a8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/sbin/sshd' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-client_1%3a8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup link of './usr/bin/ssh' before installing new version: Operation not permitted
...
```

Investigating I found that both files have the immutable attribute.

```
$:~# lsattr /usr/bin/ssh
----i---------e----- /usr/bin/ssh
$:~# lsattr /usr/sbin/sshd
----i---------e----- /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Everytime I try to change attribute of '/usr/bin/ssh' or '/usr/sbin/sshd' with the command `chattr -i /usr/bin/ssh` or `chattr -i /usr/sbin/sshd` several processes spawns throwing
`... chattr +i /usr/bin/chattr ... /usr/bin/ssh /usr/sbin/sshd` (as can be seen in the image below).

[image: chattr processes spawned]

The process is also changing attributes of the following files.

```
----i---------e----- /usr/share/doc/libbasechattr.0.so.2
----i---------e----- /usr/share/doc/libchattr-1.0.so
----i---------e----- /usr/bin/chattr
```

I can't find information on the Web for the terms `libbasechattr` and `libchattr`.

I found the same behavior in two unrelated machines that are on different sites and don't communicate directly.

System details:

- Ubuntu Server 20.04.02 LTS
- Kernel Linux 5.4.0-66-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 27 22:54:38 UTC 2021 x86_64
- OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
- Filesystem is ext4 in one machine and btrfs in the other.

Has anyone experienced this before, is this a *bug* or an *attack*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no reason to have libraries in `/usr/share/doc`, and as you point out, the “libraries” (which probably aren’t libraries, given the command shown in your `htop` screenshot) aren’t referenced anywhere. This is extremely likely to be an attack.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428722/86440) and the links therein for details of what you should do now.