# /bin/bash /var/tmp/.system/[scan]

Tags: ubuntu

I noticed a process is using 15% from my CPU.
Checking the process it is just showing [scan]

If I try to kill this process, it will rerun itself again.
When I check with ps -fp it is showing

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root     26702     1 15 16:03 ?        00:01:59 /bin/bash /var/tmp/.system/[scan]
```

Any help please?

Comment: There’s a good chance your system is compromised; see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/428721/86440) for what to do next.

Comment: And [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/q/218005/267016) too