# What is this process causing my CPU utilization to peak to 100%?

Tags: centos, iptables, yum, docker

I have used CentOS 7. I updated the CentOS version recently to install docker. Then this problem arose. I think that this problem is caused by the docker and I tried to remove it,

`yum remove docker`

but I cannot resolve this problem and /sbin/iptables file delete

[image]

How can i solve this problem? My CentOS version:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

`top`:

[image]

CPU Share:

[image]

`vmstat -n -w`

[image]

`ps`

[image]

`pstree`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process with weird random name consuming significant network and CPU resources. Is someone hacking me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428721/process-with-weird-random-name-consuming-significant-network-and-cpu-resources)

Comment: Please post text , not images